# Use \citet when there is no author

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I want to cite a book ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun), in case it matters) using `\citet`. The book has two editors but no authors, so when compiling

```
According to \citet[section 4.6]{Abramowitz70}
```

with the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style (from an Elsevier journal) I get the following in the compiled `.pdf` file:

> According to (**Author?**) [8, section 4.6]

- Is there a simple solution to make the bibliography style *use the editor when there are no authors*?
- Failing that, can I *manually specify an author* to be shown for that citation?

I prefer not to include a fake author in my `.bib` file to solve this, because the book's cover clearly mentions the editors and no authors.

Comment: Can you please prepare a short, yet complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of what you are doing? The following worked for me https://gist.github.com/moewew/f13734ca1b143b943791cd9b7d1369eb So it seems it should be possible in general, the question is why it does not work in your special case.

Comment: @moewe I’m using Elsevier’s `elsarticle-num` bibliography style. That must be the problem then. Thanks for testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your `.bib` entry looks like this

```
@book{AS,
  editor    = {Milton Abramowitz and Irene Stegun},
  title     = {Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables},
  year      = {1970},
  publisher = {Dover},
  address   = {New York},
}
```

As it turns out in the comments you use `elsarticle-num`, which produces a `.bbl` with the relevant part looking like

```
\bibitem{AS}
M.~Abramowitz, I.~Stegun (Eds.), Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
  Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables, Dover, New York, 1970.
```

`plainnat` (as style - as the name suggests - specifically designed for `natbib`) on the other hand produces

```
\bibitem[Abramowitz and Stegun(1970)]{AS}
Milton Abramowitz and Irene Stegun, editors.
\newblock \emph{Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and
  Mathematical Tables}.
\newblock Dover, New York, 1970.
```

Note the additional optional argument of `\bibitem` that holds the editor names and year. This optional argument is crucial to `\citet` working correctly. Indeed, the beginning of `natbib.sty` mentions

```
 % With standard numerical .bst files, only numerical citations are
 % possible. With an author-year .bst file, both numerical and
 % author-year citations are possible.
 %
 % If author-year citations are selected, \bibitem must have one of the
 %   following forms:
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al., 1990]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones
 %       et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citename{Jones et al., }1990]{key}...
 %   \harvarditem[Jones et al.]{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{1990}{key}...
 %
 % This is either to be made up manually, or to be generated by an
 % appropriate .bst file with BibTeX.
 %                            Author-year mode     ||   Numerical mode
 % Then, \citet{key}  ==>>  Jones et al. (1990)    ||   Jones et al. [21]
 %       \citep{key}  ==>> (Jones et al., 1990)    ||   [21]
```

Note that the situation is no better even if Abramowitz and Stegun were promoted to authors. Even then you would get the complaint **(Author?)**

If you were to load `natbib` with the `author-year` option while using `elsarticle-num`, you'd even get

> ```
> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
> ```

So the solution here is to use a `.bst` style that is compatible with `natbib`'s author-year citations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. I have included the information about the bibligraphy style in my question